# breeze createEntity not initializing one of the navigation property

Tags: breeze, navigation-properties

I am creating a breeze entity using createEntity of entitymanager. Upon creation I find that only 1 of its navigation property is null whereas others are assigned.

```
              var chargeEntity = {
              ClientId: data.ClientId,
              PatientId: data.PatientId,
              AssessmentLogId: data.AssessmentLogId,
              MedicalRecordNbr: data.Patient.MedicalRecordNbr,
              AssessmentTypeCd: data.AssessmentType.AssessmentTypeCd,
              ReviewDate: new Date(),
              Qty: 1,
              InsertDate: new Date(),
              ProductId: data.ProductId 
            };
            var charge = datacontext.createEntity('Charge', chargeEntity);
```

I find that in the charge entity, AssessmentLog navigation property is null where as others like Client, Patient and Product are assigned.
What could be the reason ?

After debugging for a while, I found that in breeze.debug.js, in the function below:

```
 proto._findEntityGroup = function (entityType) {
    return this._entityGroupMap[entityType.name];
 };
```

_entityGroupMap does not contain an entry for the navigation property AssessmentLog, hence that property is being set as null.

Answer (score 0):

The entity AssessmentLog was not in cache for the AssessmentLogId, that's why the navigation property was being set as null.

I executed a breeze query for the AssessmentLogId, and then the charge entity's AssessmentLog was correctly set.